# Show that the Turing Reduction is transitive: if $A\leq_{T}B$ and $B\leq_{T}C$ then $A\leq_{T}C$

Tags: turing-machines

I am struggling with this question, because I came up with an relatively easy proof for mapping reduction:

if  $A\leq_{M}B$ and $B\leq_{M}C$ then $A\leq_{M}C$. We know that $w \in A$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f(w) \in B$ and $w \in B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f(w) \in C$.

Let $h = g \circ f$. since $w \in A$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f(w) \in B$ we can conclude that $f(w) \in B$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $g(f(w)) \in C$ $=$ $h(w) \in C$. Thus, we know that $A\leq_{T}C$. Now this proof might be wrong, but the more important question for me is, is that proof applicable to

$A\leq_{T}B$ and $B\leq_{T}C$ then $A\leq_{T}C$?

My intuition says no, and I am looking for a different approach. All I know is that a solution of $B$ is a subalgorithm in $A$ and a solution of $C$ is a subalgorithm in $B$. It seems logical that $A\leq_{T}C$ holds aswell then, but this doesn't proof anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Turing reduction from $A$ to $B$ is a Turing Machine $M$ with an oracle for $B$ that decides $A$.

Suppose that there is also a Turing reduction $M'$ from $B$ to $C$.
We can get a Turing reduction from $A$ to $C$ (i.e., a Turing machine with an oracle for $C$ that decides $A$) by considering the Turing Machine obtained from $M$ by replacing each call to the oracle for $B$ with an execution of $M'$ (which decides $B$ given an oracle for $C$, which we have available).